# Cannot load assets in html project

Tags: gwt, libgdx

I am trying to test a html build. The thing was working right until I tried loading an image file from the asset folder.

In the asset folder I have two files: badlogic.jpg and test.png

They are both loaded the same way:

```
varname = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("<filename>"));
```

The project is build with:

```
./gradlew html:superDev
```

Loading the badlogic.jpg file works just fine, but loading any other file in the same folder does not work and gives the following error:

> GwtApplication: exception: Couldn't load image 'test.png', file does not exist
>   Couldn't load image 'test.png', file does not exist.

I am loading badlogic.jpg first. I have confirmed that both files are in the same folder.

This is not a problem on android and desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just as I posted the question I found the answer.

My first thought was that I needed to clear my browser cache. I cleared it multiple times but it didn't work.

But.... I was testing the project in one window and using another to do other things. The browser window I used to clear the cache was firefox, the window I used to test the project was chrome... So... that's why it didn't work.
It works now that I have cleared the cache in the browser I use to test the project.
I think its time for bed.